# Macro involving TikZ node does not work

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I'm having difficulty with a macro I created;

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}


\newcommand{\LabelText}[3]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [text width=\widthof{#1}, text centered, draw=none, thick, rectangle, inner sep = 0pt, outer sep = 0pt, fill=#3]
        {#2};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}


\newcommand{\padv}[1]{\LabelText{#1}{\strut Adv}{blue!30}}%


\begin{document}

This is an \padv{adverb}


\end{document}
```

I use it for labelling parts of speech in a linguistics class. Errors are

```
./MWE for labeltext.tex:22: Undefined control sequence. [This is an 
\padv{adverb}]
./MWE for labeltext.tex:22: Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `adverb' (in '{adverb}'). [This is an \padv{adverb}]
./MWE for labeltext.tex:22: Undefined control sequence. [This is an \padv{adverb}]
./MWE for labeltext.tex:22: Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `adverb' (in '{adverb}'). [This is an \padv{adverb}]
```

I've been using this macros successfully for years, but for some reason it has suddenly stopped working. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Macro `\widthof` does not belong to TikZ, but to package `calc`. TikZ provides the math function `width` for measuring text strings in quotes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\LabelText}[3]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(LabelText.base)]
    \node [
      text width=width("#1"),
      text centered,
      draw=none,
      thick,
      rectangle,
      inner sep=0pt,
      outer sep=0pt,
      fill={#3},
    ] (LabelText) {#2};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand{\padv}[1]{\LabelText{#1}{\strut Adv}{blue!30}}%

\begin{document}
  This is an \padv{adverb}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Wonderful. Thanks! The strange thing is, I'd been using this macro successfully for years...

Comment: @NickRiches It's not actually strange, `\widthof` etc. was defined in version 2.x of TikZ, but it was removed in version 3, so after upgrading code with `\widthof` would stop working.